# Detection of virtual background on video using ffmpeg

Tags: video, ffmpeg, video-processing, detection

I am trying with ffmpeg to detect the use of a virtual background on a video, like [the ones used in Google Meet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZrRjI.png). I got some ideas, but none seem to work:

- **Egde color:** When using a chroma key you can get shades of green/blue on the outline of the subject. This is called spill, and can be detectable, but gets discarded by the fact that you dont need a chroma key to fake a background (example: Google Meet).
- **Still image:** Most of virtual backgrounds are a still image pasted behind the subject. The problem with detecting this is that most of the real backgrounds also are like still images, without much movement.
- **Blur:** When faking a background without a chroma key the outline of the subject becomes very blurry (this is more noticeable when the subject moves), but I can't find a way to detect it using ffmpeg.

How can I do this? I'm open to trying other tecniques such as AI.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Well how do YOU know when you're looking at a virtual background? Think about what clues you get and then write a code to look for same clues. Also look into `image paste forgery detection` for techniques on detecting some "pasted in" pixels (that do not match Histogram or Frequency of surrounding pixels)...